# Dependencies issues and no login

Tags: networking, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome, 17.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 and then I couldn't login. It gets me back to the login page when I entered my password. I restarted my computer and then, I couldn't access to the login page. It stays stuck with the gnome 3 logo...
But when I started my computer on recovery mode, I opened a root terminal and it shows that there is dependencies that are not satisfied. But no suggested command seems to work...
I tried to reinstall Ubuntu with a bootable key. But it stays stuck on the unity loading page. So I couldn't solve it this way either. 
Moreover, when I ping 8.8.8.8, it shows "connect: network unreachable". And ifconfig only displays io. I have no idea of what keywords I should use on Google. 
Is anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Update : when I type `apt --fix-broken install`, there is an error :file /var/lib/dpkg/lock in read mode only. And I cannot delete it even if I am root

Comment: That is a wall of text without much information. What errors ? How can you ping google if you can not login ???

Comment: During the release upgrade, did the system offer you a 'Partial Upgrade'? If so, did you choose to accept it? Or did you refuse it?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry...
Ok, when I want to update my packages, it says that it couldn't reach the different repositories. And when I tried the command `apt-get --fix-broken install` on the root terminal it says that the needed packages could not be downloaded. To access to this terminal, I selected the recovery mode in grub in directory that called "other options with ubuntu". Then I opened a root terminal. This is where I tried to ping google.

Comment: I didn't remember anything about a 'Partial Ugrade' choice. But I left my computer during the upgrade...

Comment: The problem with the lockfile seems completely separate from your problem. Wait a while and try again. "Read mode only" also seems unrelated, but is confusing. Please try to be as accurate as possible when copying error messages - there are *dozens* of possible causes, each with a different way to fix, so the error messages are important.